# rmagick install fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I cloned two ruby projects using BitBucket + Source Tree. When I execute bundle install, it runs successfully in one project directory however fails in other project directory with following error:

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
```

Can anyone help me to determine the issue?

Comment: @suresh.g : bundle update doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try :

```
brew install imagemagick
```